# How do I convert C++ function to assembly(x86_64)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, assembly, x86-64

This is my .CPP file

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "C" void KeysAsm(int arr[], int n, int thetha, int rho);

// Keep this and call it from assembler
extern "C"
void crim(int *xp, int *yp) {
    int temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp+2;
}

// Translate this into Intel assembler
void KeysCpp(int arr[], int n, int thetha, int rho){
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                crim(&arr[j], &arr[j + 1]);
            }
        }
        arr[i]= arr[i] + thetha / rho * 2 - 4;
    }
}

// Function to print an array 
void printArray(int arr[], int size){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << "\n";
    cout << endl;
}


int main() {
    int gamma1[]{
        9,
        270,
        88,
        -12,
        456,
        80,
        45,
        123,
        427,
        999
    };

    int gamma2[]{
        900,
        312,
        542,
        234,
        234,
        1,
        566,
        123,
        427,
        111
    };

    printf("Array:\n");
    printArray(gamma1, 10);

    KeysAsm(gamma1, 10, 5, 6);
    printf("Array Result Asm:\n");
    printArray(gamma1, 10);

    KeysCpp(gamma2, 10, 5, 6);
    printf("Array Result Cpp:\n");
    printArray(gamma2, 10);
}
```

What I want to do is, convert the *KeysCpp* function into assembly language and call it from this very .CPP file. I want to keep the *crim* function as it is in .CPP, while only converting the *KeysCpp*.

Here is my .ASM file

```
PUBLIC KeysAsm

includelib kernel32.lib

_DATA   SEGMENT
EXTERN crim:PROC
_DATA ENDS

_TEXT   SEGMENT

KeysAsm PROC
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    sub     rsp, 40
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-24], rdi
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-28], esi
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-32], edx
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-36], ecx
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
    jmp      L3

 L3:
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-28]
    sub     eax, 1
    cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], eax
    jl       L7

 L4:
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-28]
    sub     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
    sub     eax, 1
    cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], eax
    jl       L6

 L5:
    add     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 1

 L6:
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
    cdqe
    lea     rdx, [0+rax*4]
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
    add     rax, rdx
    mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rax]
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
    cdqe
    add     rax, 1
    lea     rcx, [0+rax*4]
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
    add     rax, rcx
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax]
    cmp     edx, eax
    jle      L5
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
    cdqe
    add     rax, 1
    lea     rdx, [0+rax*4]
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
    add     rdx, rax
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
    cdqe
    lea     rcx, [0+rax*4]
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
    add     rax, rcx
    mov     rsi, rdx
    mov     rdi, rax
    call    crim

 L7:
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 0
    jmp      L4

KeysAsm ENDP

_TEXT   ENDS



END
```

I am using Visual Studio 2017 to run this project.

I am getting next error when I run this code.

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF74B0E429C in MatrixMultiplication.exe: Stack cookie instrumentation code detected a stack-based buffer overrun. occurred

Comment: converting from v++ is what your compiler does - not understanding your motivation here

Comment: When and where does KeysAsm in the assembly code return? I can't seem to find any code that pops from the stack or ret code.

Comment: You asm looks like it's expecting the x86-64 System V calling convention, with args in RDI, ESI, EDX, ECX.  But you said you're compiling with Visual Studio, so that will use the Windows x64 calling convention: RCX, EDX, R8D, R9D.  And when you `call crim`, it can use shadow space (32 bytes above its return address).  It looks like you got this asm from un-optimized compiler output , probably from https://godbolt.org/ using GCC for Linux, without using `-mabi=ms`.  And then modified it to make the loop infinite?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/YPTxKTYYK compiles just the function you wanted, with a prototype for `crim`.  IDK why you don't want to let a compiler inline it and simplify your function (https://godbolt.org/z/z1zcbMGTG), but ok.

Comment: You can already see your disassembled code in Visual C++. If I remember the shortcut it's `Ctrl + Alt + D` when a breakpoint is hit or your app is paused. That's another way to learn what happens to your compiled C++ code

Answer (score 2):

Your asm looks like it's expecting the x86-64 System V calling convention, with args in RDI, ESI, EDX, ECX. But you said you're compiling with Visual Studio, so the compiler-generated code will use the Windows x64 calling convention: RCX, EDX, R8D, R9D.

And when you call `crim`, it can use shadow space (32 bytes above its return address, which you didn't reserve space for).

It looks like you got this asm from un-optimized compiler output, probably from https://godbolt.org/z/ea4MPh81r using GCC for Linux, without using `-mabi=ms` to override the default `-mabi=sysv` when compiling for non-Windows targets. And then you modified it to make the loop infinite, with a `jmp` at the bottom instead of a `ret`?  Maybe a different GCC version than 12.2 since the label numbers and code don't match exactly.

(The signs of being un-optimized compiler output are all the reloads from `[rbp-whatever]`, and redoing sign-extension before using an `int` to index an array with `cdqe`.  A human would know the `int` must be non-negative.  And being GCC specifically, the numbered label like `.L1:` etc. where you just removed the `.`, and of heavily using `RAX` for as much as possible in a debug build.  And choices like `lea     rdx, [0+rax*4]` to copy-and-shift, and the exact syntax it used to print that instruction in Intel syntax match GCC.)

---

#### To compile a single function for Windows x64, isolate it and give the compiler only prototypes for anything it calls

```
extern "C" void crim(int *xp, int *yp);  // prototype only

void KeysCpp(int arr[], int n, int thetha, int rho){
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                crim(&arr[j], &arr[j + 1]);
            }
        }
        arr[i]= arr[i] + thetha / rho * 2 - 4;
    }
}
```

Then on Godbolt, **use `gcc -O3 -mabi=ms`, or use MSVC** which always targets Windows. https://godbolt.org/z/Mj5Gb54b5 shows both GCC and MSVC with optimization enabled.

```
KeysCpp(int*, int, int, int):    ; demangled name
        cmp     edx, 1
        jle     .L11            ; "shrink wrap" optimization: early-out on n<=1 before saving regs
        push    r15             ; save some call-preserved regs
        push    r14
        lea     r14, [rcx+4]    ; arr + 1
        push    r13
        mov     r13, rcx
```

Unfortunately GCC fails to hoist the `thetha / rho * 2 - 4` loop-invariant, instead redoing `idiv` every time through the loop.  Seems like an obvious optimization since those are local vars whose address hasn't been taken at all, and it keeps `thetha` (typo for `theta`?) and `rho` in registers.  So MSVC is much more efficient here.  Clang also misses this optimization.